# Regular expression match string and then next two lines

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a following string:

```
  window.universal = {
    yada yada ydada.....
  };
```

The following return the first line. I need next two as well

```
re.search(r'.*window.universal.*', content).group(0)
```

I tired re.MULTILINE, \s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need DOTALL.
- also the two `.*` will give you almost everything with dotall.

try this:

```
 re.search(r'window.universal = {.*?};',content,re.DOTALL).group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `r'(?s).*pattern.*'`

- `re.M` (multi-line)  <<< we don't need this option
- `re.S` (dot matches all)